# PHP Code seems to not work

Tags: php, date

I just asked a question and got a quick and useful response but this code doesn't seem to be functioning correctly after a few edits.

```
$firstDate = '2013-09-17 21:20:24';

echo $firstDate;
echo '<br>';

$datetime1 = new DateTime($firstDate);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($secondDate);
$interval  = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
if ($interval->a <= 7)
{
    if($interval->y !== 0) 
    {
    $elapsed   = $interval->format('%y years ago');
    }
    else
    if($interval->m !== 0) 
    {
    $elapsed   = $interval->format('%m months ago');
    }
    else
    if($interval->a !== 0) 
    {
    $elapsed   = $interval->format('%a days ago');
    }
    else
    if($interval->h !== 0) 
    {
    $elapsed   = $interval->format('%h hours ago');
    }
    else
    if($interval->i !== 0) 
    {
    $elapsed   = $interval->format('%i minutes ago');
    }
    else
    if($interval->S !== 0) 
    {
    $elapsed   = $interval->format('%S seconds ago');
    }

    $elapsed   = str_replace(array('0 years ago', ' 0 months ago', ' 0 days ago',  ' 0 hours ago', ' 0 minutes ago'), '', $elapsed);
$elapsed   = str_replace(array('1 years ago', ' 1 months ago', ' 1 days ago',  ' 1 hours ago', ' 1 minutes ago'), array('1 year ago', '1 month ago', ' 1 day ago', ' 1 hour ago', ' 1 minute ago'), $elapsed);
    echo $elapsed;
}
else 
{
    echo $firstDate;
}
```

The code is supposed to give the format X days ago or X seconds ago

but it stops working after days so I don't get minutes or seconds. Why is this not working?

Comment: Where is `$secondDate`?

Comment: Oh wow... I need that too. Right.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the user forgetting to declare a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you allow the viewing of errors and notices in your php.ini file for your development server.
[How to enable notices on my development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670142/how-to-enable-notices-on-my-development-server)

When running the code you provided, I get a `Notice: Undefined variable: secondDate` on `line 11`, and `Undefined property: DateInterval::$a` on `line 23`.

It seems you are asking PHP to format a number using incomplete data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are using `$interval->a` for days and `$interval->S` for seconds. Correct is `$interval->days` (for `if ($interval->days <= 7)`), `$interval->d` (for `if($interval->d !== 0)`) and `$interval->s` (for `if($interval->s !== 0)`).

See [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for correct parameters.

---

You can use this code:

#### Use example :

```php
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-09-01 00:22:35');
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-09-01 00:22:35', true);
```

#### Output :

```
17 days ago
17 days, 1 hour, 40 minutes, 12 seconds ago
```

**[Link to the function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)**