# How to enable notices on my development server - Not working

Tags: php

I'm referring to [How to enable notices on my development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670142/how-to-enable-notices-on-my-development-server)

I expect the following code shall give me some warning, when I execute it through, as my `$a` is not explicitly declared as array

`php a.php`

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_NOTICE);

$a['key'] = 123;
echo $a['key'] . "\n";
```

However, no warning message being printed. Is there anything I had missed?

The PHP I'm using is PHP 5.5.3. I'm not sure this matters?

Comment: That's what I didn't ever notice in PHP! That's weird to me as I always initialize my arrays and expected PHP To generate NOTICE for assigning to uninitialized arrays. Good to know, but not a very good habit to use!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expect the following code shall give me some warning, when I execute it through, as my $a is not explicitly declared as array

Wrong... by writing `$a['key'] = 123;` you declare an array and set the `key` key to the integer number 123. That's a valid PHP array initialization. (The PHP version does not matter in this case.)

**To explicitely produce an error notice for testing purposes…**

If you want to provoke an error notice for testing purposes, you could add this line:

```
count($ThisIsNotDefinedOnPurpose);
```

which will produce an error notice saying

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ThisIsNotDefinedOnPurpose in … on line …
```

Comment: Sadly, this is the case. I'd love for it to generate a notice.

Comment: @Wrikken Just added an example of that to my answer. See *"To explicitely produce an error notice…*"

Comment: Heh, I'm not the OP, I know how to create (and avoid) notices, it just saddens me that `$a['key']='value';` does _not_ create a notice, as it could have saved me some valuable debugging time in the time before I got an editor which highlighted undeclared variables. But thanks nonetheless :)

Comment: @Wrikken I did notice you were not the OP, but I kinda misinterpreted your `I'd love for it to generate a notice.`, thinking you wanted an example of what would produce an error. Anyway, I agree with you that an error would've been logic from a regular coder (C/C++ for example) point of view. Yet,  PHP is known for accepting almost anything for initialization and whether we like it or not — from a PHP point of view, that `$a['key'] = 123;` practically is a valid PHP array initialization. Oh well… it's PHP. ;)