# put php variable on src html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to do when I put a code, print the code on the iframe url

```html
form method="GET">
  <div>
    Codigo del video que quieres ver: <input type="text" id="ver" name="ver" placeholder="Codigo Video">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if ($_GET['ver']) {
echo $ver ?>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $image; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Turn notcies on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670142/how-to-enable-notices-on-my-development-server

Comment: Welcome to SO!.  Check out this post on how to ask a question that is likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I'm really not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: What error are you getting? what is $image ? Is iFrame generated? Please explain in more details what is working and what is not working.

Comment: The iFrame is successfully generated but we can't put $ver in the url, when I see the code of the web doesn't appear the text that I want to put
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/(I need to have the $ver here with the text that have $ver)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```html
<form method="GET">
  <div>
    Codigo del video que quieres ver: <input type="text" id="ver" name="ver" placeholder="Codigo Video">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if ($_GET['ver']) {
$ver = $_GET['ver'];
echo $ver;
echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$ver.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yeah something like this but now the code doesn't work

Comment: Problem solved I delete the echo $ver and now works thank you so much